# Set the ngClick event handler for the capturing phase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

Is it possible to set the `ngClick` event handler to the capturing phase as described in [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). I want to prevent events from trickling down to the children and bubbling up again when a condition is met for the parent during the capturing phase.

Answer (score -2):

In all angular event directives you can use $event object (it is jquery/jquery-lite event object). So, you can do this:

```
ng-click="someAction(); $event.stopPropagation()"
```

Comment: Of course this is not what he was looking for... Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296808/can-angularjs-ng-click-process-events-during-the-capturing-phase