# Can angularjs ng-click process events during the capturing phase?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Is it possible to have angularjs ng-click process events during the capturing phase instead of bubbling phase?  I want to aggregate data from each of the parent elements in order starting from the parent and ending with the element that was clicked on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lets see the source code of `ng-click` at [ngEventDirs.js#L50](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L50)

As you can see the `ng-click` and all other event directives using `.on()`.

So, the answer is **No, it is not possible**.

If you really need it, you could write a custom directive for that. For example, modify the code of `ng-click` a bit:

```
.directive('captureClick', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      var fn = $parse(attrs.captureClick);
      return function(scope, element) {
        element[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            fn(scope, {
              $event: event
            });
          });
        }, true);
      };
    }
  }
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<div title="A" ng-click="onBubbled($event)" capture-click="onCaptured($event)">
  <div title="B" ng-click="onBubbled($event)" capture-click="onCaptured($event)">
    <div title="C" ng-click="onBubbled($event)" capture-click="onCaptured($event)">
      Yo!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/SVPv0fCNRQX4JXHeL47X?p=preview