# Hide keystrokes from window-wide listeners

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm making an extension for Chrome to be used on Youtube. The extension adds an overlay on top of the video with a text input. However, typing into the extension triggers Youtube's various keystroke listeners (e.g. `space -> pause`). `event.stopPropagation()` does nothing, neither does `return false` at the end of the Angular event callback.

My current (successfully prototyped but not yet implemented) solution is to wrap the input in an iframe, which will pass messages back to the parent window:

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector("#wrapped-input").addEventListener("input", function(){
  result.innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

I feel that this solution is a bit of a hack, and I'm hoping to find something more elegant. As an aside, I am using AngularJS for the app, so if there are any Angular-specific workarounds, I'd love to know those too. Thoughts?

---

**EDIT**
Current solution:

```
<iframe id="wrapper-frame"></iframe>
```

...

```
link: {
  var input = '<input id="inner-input" />';

  var wrap = $window.document.querySelector('#wrapper-iframe').contentWindow.document;
  $scope.commentInput = wrap.querySelector('#inner-input');

  wrap.open();
  wrap.write(input);
  wrap.close();

  $scope.commentInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
    var val = this.value;
    $scope.$applyAsync(function(){
      $scope.inputContent = val;
    });
  });
}
```

It works, but still -- iframe. Bleh, hack. I will leave the question open in case if someone has a better idea.

Comment: Have you tried `addEventListener` for `keydown` with third parameter (useCapture) set to `true`?

Comment: I haven't! I'm using angularJS, so I don't really use addEventListener in the program. Could you suggest a good way to work it in?

Comment: Define a new directive and use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296808/can-angularjs-ng-click-process-events-during-the-capturing-phase

Comment: Tried it, it half-worked: characters I typed now appeared in the textbox, but Youtube was still hearing the events and the player reacted accordingly.