# Leave alone keydown events usable for focused descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, keydown

I have a (home made) table with a few physical rows a many logical rows, which I want to scroll (also) using the keyboard. In case a descendant is focused which understands the key, I want the event to be handled by the descendant and to be ignored by my table.

Maybe the code makes it clear:

```
scroll.keydown = function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey | e.controlKey | e.altKey) return;
    var isText = e.target.type === "text";
    var K = $.ui.keyCode;
    switch (e.keyCode) {
    case K.HOME: if (isText) return; scroll.move(-1000000); break;
    case K.END: if (isText) return; scroll.move(+1000000); break;
    case K.PAGE_UP: scroll.move(-10); break;
    case K.PAGE_DOWN: scroll.move(+10); break;
    case K.UP: scroll.move(-1); break;
    case K.DOWN: scroll.move(+1); break;
    default: return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
};


<table tabindex="0" ng-keydown="scroll.keydown($event)" ...>
      ... <input ...>
```

*It works perfectly, but it's very stupid*: The table *knows* that it contains `input` elements and it *knows* that such an element can make use of e.g., the `HOME` key, so it makes a test to leave it alone.

That's very wrong. Now, I've added a `select`, which would need a similar test in the `DOWN` case to keep it working.

Funnily, there's another `ng-keydown`-using component inside my table, which handles events very similarly, but there is no problem:

- When I press `DOWN` while my inner component is focused, it gets to the event first and everything is fine.
- When I press `DOWN` while a `select` is focused, my table gets the event first and gets scrolled. What I want *instead*, is that the select opens as usual.

Tested in Chromium Version 60.0.3112.113 using angularjs v1.5.0 and 1.12.1.

## Plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/nr2JVJU1U16465F1WKkC?p=preview

## Clarification

- Any event meaningless for the currently focused descendant should be processed by the table.
- For example, `PAGE_UP` means nothing for an `input`, so the table should be scrolled, even if the focused child processes some other events, like e.g., `HOME`.
- That's why I added `if (isText) return;` to `HOME` and `END` only which are useful in an `input` and not to the other keys, which are not.

Comment: Can you simply capture the keydown event on the `<select>` element, and stop it from propagating/bubbling? That will prevent its parent from capturing the keydown event :)

Comment: If the `table` is getting the event before the `select` element you will have to use the `useCapture`, however I'm not sure it's implemented by angular :(. Are you sure this is the case here?

Comment: @Terry This'd mean, I'd have to add handlers to all selects... that's not much better. OK, I could write a directive adding a listener... but there could be already other listeners.

Comment: Are you able to create a simple jsfiddle as an example? Even with a simple table with a select inside it...

Comment: Alternatively, check `e.target` in the parent when the keydown event is fired. If it’s from a select element then return false, or the likes.

Comment: @Terry That's exactly what I did for the `select` and what I hate doing. This way the table must know everything about all its children.

Comment: @Dekel Do you mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/25301610/581205? Plunk done, s. edit.

Comment: @Dekel That's strange. Angular does bubbling, which is actually fine, as I want processing from the inside. But native reactions seem to come last.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the code of your plunkr and did a very small change to help you get what you wanted.

At the very top of you **$scope.keydown** function, I've added a condition that checks if the target is an input or a select, and then it will ignore the scroll.

This works with the nodeName property, like this (check the **$scope.keydown** function):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) data.push({
    id: i,
    value: i * i
  });


  var scroll = $scope.scroll = {
    start: 0,
    limit: 10,

    move: function(delta) {
      var start = scroll.start + delta;
      start = Math.max(start, 0);
      start = Math.min(start, data.length - scroll.limit);
      scroll.start = start;
    },

    keydown: function(e) {
      // With the e.target.nodeName you can
      // can check if the keydown is being
      // triggered from the input or the select
      // and then avoid the table scroll
      if(e.target.nodeName === 'INPUT' || e.target.nodeName === 'SELECT') {
        return false;
      }

      if (e.shiftKey | e.controlKey | e.altKey) return;
      var isText = e.target.type === "text";
      var K = $.ui.keyCode;
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case K.HOME:
          if (isText) return;
          scroll.move(-1000000);
          break;
        case K.END:
          if (isText) return;
          scroll.move(+1000000);
          break;
        case K.PAGE_UP:
          scroll.move(-10);
          break;
        case K.PAGE_DOWN:
          scroll.move(+10);
          break;
        case K.UP:
          scroll.move(-1);
          break;
        case K.DOWN:
          scroll.move(+1);
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    },
  };

  $scope.visibleData = [];
  $scope.$watchCollection("scroll",
    function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < scroll.limit; ++i) {
        $scope.visibleData[i] = data[i + scroll.start];
      }
    });

});
```

```css
table:focus {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery-ui@1.10.4" data-semver="1.10.4" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li>Click in the input</li>
    <li>Press Shift-Tab</li>
    <li>Observe thar arrow-up and down control the outer select.</li>
    <li>Pres Tabl twice</li>
    <li>Observe that the the arrows scroll the table instead!</li>
  </ul>

  <select name="outer">
    <option>first</option>
    <option>second</option>
  </select>

  <table tabindex="1" ng-keydown="scroll.keydown($event)">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input name="unused">
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="select">
          <option>first</option>
          <option>second</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>row</th>
      <th>value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in visibleData">
      <td>{{x.id}}</td>
      <td>{{x.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Apologies for not being clear with what I exactly want (and confusing "ancestor" with "descendant" :D). I've added a paragraph.

Comment: No problems, @maaartinus. Did you check my answer? I think it will help your problem. Just run the code snippet.